# Matrix Multiplication in C - Problem with inputs

Tags: c, loops, matrix, multiplication

I've written a program which carries out matrix multiplication using functions. The function which i presume is wrong is as follows:

```
void obtainMatrixElems(int mtrx[][10], int row_elems, int col_elems){
    printf("Kindly enter matrix elements: \n");

    for(int x = 0; x < row_elems; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < col_elems; y++){
            printf("Enter element at position %d,%d: \n", x+1, y+1);
            scanf("&d", &mtrx[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always, always, always, without fail, always check the value returned by `scanf`.  Always.  It's not at all surprising that you would have "problem with Inputs" if you aren't even validating that `scanf` has parsed the input as you expect.

Comment: how the `RESULTANT MATRIX` is computed and printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing a "+" at `multAns[x][y] = matrix1[x][y] * matrix2[x][y];`.

It should rather be:

```
// Also note the change variables used for referencing cells ...
multAns[x][y] += matrix1[x][z] * matrix2[z][y];
```

In case your last operation result is `0` then this explains why you get a 0 matrix..

EDIT:

The sign is one of the problems .. There is also something wrong with the way you get input from the user.

```
    for(int x = 0; x < row_elems; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < col_elems; y++){
            printf("Enter element at position %d,%d: \n", x+1, y+1);
            // Note the change of "&" to "%" and the extra sequence
            // "\r\n" which expects the user to press ENTER (i.e.:
            // new line) between input cells
            rc = scanf("%d\r\n", &mtrx[x][y]);
            if (rc != 1) {
                printf("ERROR: scanf did not proceed as expected\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: didn't solve it unfortunately :/

Comment: @aadinnvv What matrix did you try with?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your call to `scanf`
It should read

```
scanf("%d", &mtrx[x][y]);
```

Also take care with hitting the `Enter` Key after each input. To be safe you should catch it. Use something like

```
scanf(" %d", &mtrx[x][x]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I've tried your suggestion and it works but only for entering the first element of the matrix. After the first element is entered it seems to skip over the rest and terminate.

Comment: Did you also try the second `scanf` line?

Comment: yes, it works that way but outputs aren't as expected. I will look further into it myself, thanks for the help!